# PHP + Jquery Change Value of Textbox according to two Dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I try to update text box value according to 2 dropdown. 1 drop down contain price1 and other drop down contain price 2, now I want that when user select price from both drop down then textbox display like that "**price1 + price2 = total**" How can I marge both value in single textbox value ? my price comes from database. Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/LxRVz/)

PHP CODE

```
 <div class="three columns">
                    <div class="picker">
                        <select name="city" required>
                        <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
                            <?php 
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM area");
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                            ?>
                                <option value="New"><?php echo $row['city']."( $ ".$row['area'].")";; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="four columns">
                <div class="picker">
                    <select name="position" required>

                        <?php 
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pricing");
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['position']; ?>"><?php echo $row['position']."( $ ".$row['price'].")"; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="two columns">
                Total
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns">
                <div class="field">
                  <input class="input" type="total" id="total" placeholder="" name="total" disabled/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a class on both combo and write one event this way:

```
$('.combo').change(function() {
    $('#firstvalue').val(parseInt($('#combo').val()) +parseInt($('#combo1').val()));
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/StBf9/1/)

or you can do this way:

```
$('.combo').change(function() {
    $('#firstvalue').val($('#combo').val() +"+"+$('#combo1').val()+"=");
    $('#firstvalue1').val(parseInt($('#combo').val()) +parseInt($('#combo1').val()));
});
```

[**SECOND DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWUV7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using variables:

if you wanted to sum of two dropdown options then you have to give integer value of the seond dropdown not the string(like a3,a4 should be 3,4). see demo html.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    price1=0;
    price2 =0;
    $('#combo').change(function() {
          price1= this.value;
          $('#firstvalue').val(parseInt(price1)+parseInt(price2));

    });


  $('#combo1').change(function() {
    price2 = this.value;
    $('#firstvalue').val(parseInt(price1)+parseInt(price2));
  });
});
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxRVz/6/)

Comment: Hi, that's what I want, but how can I add addition ? like if value 1 is "5" and second value is "12" then result in textbox is like 5 + 12 = 17

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.combo').change(function() {
    $('#firstvalue').val(parseInt($('#combo').val()) +parseInt($('#combo1').val()));
});


$('#combo1').change(function() {
    $('#firstvalue1').val($('#combo1').val());
});
});
```