# Bootstrap Select from SQL Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any module for bootstrap to make a Select button to open a table that is a query to a SQL database? For instance an input on the form and when you click on the icon it opens a SQL table query with multi column and also if possile automatic fill the form with the values from that row. I think it's called a Datachooser.

Let's say I have an SQL table with the following columns:

Name | Username | PhoneNumber

And I have 3 inputs on a bootstrap form:

Name:
Username:
PhoneNumber:

My intention is have Username and Phone Number read only, and when I click the input Name open a dropdown list that shows all rows of the SQL table and on the selection of one row it automatically writes the values on the inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify for what purpose it's needed? So others can make assumption or suggest.

Comment: Of course. I just updated the question.

Comment: So what you specifically want is to get DropDownList value to input or TextBox? What are you using HTML or ASP.NET tags? It's easy to implement.

Comment: Yes precisally but I would like that dropdown list to have multiple columns and each column updates a different input. It's HTML.

Comment: I think, it is almost impossible to have multiple columns. How may columns do you want to get?

Comment: 3 columns would be enough.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to have three columns in a DropDownList. Is this HTML inputs I mean what you are using to retrieve data PHP or ASP.NET?

Comment: It's php, the dropdown data would come from sql array of 3 columns and I would like to update the 3 inputs with data from the selected row.

Comment: Ah! Got it. When you select a value from DropDownList, then the three inputs will be filled with related data. Unfortunately I've done this with ASP.NET MVC. Will be providing an example of it in PHP. Make it sure I am correct about the scenario.

Comment: Ok, I would appreciate it.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865247/php-jquery-change-value-of-textbox-according-to-two-dropdown

Comment: Perfect, it helped me to reach what I need.